# Is installation of packages like mongoose ,mocha , nodemon is required in every new project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, nodemon

I am learning mongodb, and I have already installed packages like mocha, mongoose, and nodemon in the previous project using npm install command, and I am working on a new project, so do I need to install all these packages again, as I have already installed int the previous project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you didn't use `npm install -g <packages>` then yes, you should installed them again if needed. When install with `npm install <packages>` installed packages get placed in a `node-modules` folder in your project root directory